# Linear Regression with Bootstrapping

Tags: regression, bootstrap, outliers

I wish to run a linear regression model, with a dependent variable Y and several explanatory variables.

The distribution of Y looks like this:

[image]

Clearly not normally distributed. The sample size is about 40 observations.

In this problem I wish to use SPSS, and I didn't find an option for robust regression. This leads me to bootstrapping.

Can I use linear regression with bootstrapping when I have skewed data like this, with an outlier? Do you have other suggestions for modeling this kind of data?

Any tips will be most appreciated ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

1. Linear regression does **not** require a normally distributed dependent variable, only the error term should be normally distributed ( but that is only important in small samples)
2. A bootstrap with outliers means that your estimates of the sampling distributions are going to be bimodal. That is fine if you think the outliers are real, but you again rely a lot on those special observations and they better be right.